# Displaying special characters from sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm struggling to display French characters and the £ sign from my database. They appear fine in the phpmyadmin display, but appear as question marks in diamonds on my web page.

I have set the tables to utf8_bin in the database, and inserted 
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"
in my header.

It makes no difference. Please can anyone help me? I have been searching for an answer for hours and am not getting anywhere!
thanks...

Comment: are you set utf8 in html too

Comment: And don't forget `mysqli_set_charset`

Comment: thanks - I've put charset="utf-8" in the head, is that what you mean  gvgvgvijayan? Or should it go somewhere else?

Comment: Re. mysqli_set_charset - I have attempted this but I am getting error messages... how should I use it? Perhaps I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to user char set ISO-8859-1
this might help

Comment: I tried putting that in the header instead, and it didn't help.